# How to terminate a program using SIGALRM

Tags: c, vfork

So basically I have 4-5 functions in my program. It is a lot of lines of codes and reading and writing from a file and it could end in an infinite loop (worse case) and I would like to terminate my program if it goes beyond lets say 20 seconds. below code is not working, my program hangs and the OS terminates it for me instead of the program terminating itself. I think the main problem I am having is the alarm is set in the main and when the alarm time limit is reached the process is executing in another function and this is causing the program to shut without closing files and killing child processes. This is what I have for now:

```
volatile sig_atomic_t keep_going = 1;

/* The signal handler just clears the flag and re-enables itself. */
void
catch_alarm (int sig)
{
    printf("Alarm went off");
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
void function1
{}
void forkingfunction()
{
or(i=0;i<size;i++,temp++)
        {

             pid_t pID = vfork();

               if (pID == 0)                // child
               { 
                   printf("\nchild pid %d\n",getpid());
                    //open some files and read and write
                     function1();
                      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                       kill(pID,SIGKILL);
                       }
               }
               else if (pID < 0)            // failed to fork
               {
                   perror("Failed to fork:");
               }
}
void function2
{
function1();
}
int main()
{
int options
while(options){
switch (options)
{
case 1:
case 2:
}
}
signal (SIGALRM, catch_alarm);

          alarm (0.1);//testing for 0.1 seconds 
function1();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile. Please post a minimal, reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

there is only a certain set of function which can be executed safely from a signal handler. And `exit` is **not** one of them. Neither is `printf`.

You might able to use the `_exit()` function instead (with underscore in front). However it will only exit the top-most process, leaving the children running.

You can still kill everything using `kill(0, signal)`, as here.

```
void catch_alarm (int sig) {
   kill(0, SIGTERM);
}
```

Here is an example of a working poc code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

void catch_alarm (int sig) {
    kill (0,SIGTERM);
}

void forkingfunction()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++,i++) {
        pid_t pID = fork();
        if (pID == 0) { 
            sleep(5);
            printf("\nchild pid %d\n",getpid());
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        else if (pID < 0) {
            perror("Failed to fork:");
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    signal (SIGALRM, catch_alarm);
    alarm (1);//testing for 0.1 seconds 
    forkingfunction();
    sleep(10);
    printf("\nnormal exit\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code, as it is right now, might loop in the `while (options)` loop forever, not even getting a chance to set the handler or the alarm. Also, it cannot be compiled at all due to syntactic issues.  I updated my answer with a working example.

Comment: won't the program do nothing when the sleep(10) is executed?

Comment: I tried the example, but instead of just terminating it logs me out of the linux server and says "connection has been unexpectedly closed, server sent command exit status 143"

Comment: Now you have to figure out what you want to do. I guess in your case you need to keep a list of all alive children forked and kill them one by one (`kill(childpid,SIGTERM)`) in the handler, then use `_exit(0)` or `_Exit(0)` to exit with a normal status. This would require some programming on your side.

Comment: void handler(int sig)
{
 exit(0);
}
void catch_alarm (int sig)
{
 int i;
 for(i=0;i<(length+1);i++)
 {
  if(PID[i]!=0)

  {    kill (PID[i],SIGTERM);}
    signal(SIGTERM,handler);

 }
 //exit(0);

} Just tried this but still gives me error. Here the PID stores the alive children, value is 0 if the child was killed. length is the number of children forked +1 for the parent process

Answer (score 0):

So after spending more than 24 hrs trying to fix this. The solution was actually simple. Keep a global array of PID of children alive +1 for parent PID. before sending the kill(PID, SIGTERM) we have to mention a handler for SIGTERM which sleeps till the process is killed. Thus a graceful exit.